# csrf_token() in Laravel 5

Tags: csrf, laravel-5

I need to use the value of the csrf_token() in a config file, but that makes laravel crash.

Also, I tried to set it on AppServiceProvider, but it returns a null value.

In Laravel 4.2 you could access the csrf token in a config file without any problem.

I'm curently using Laravel 5.0.1.

example code:

```
config\foo.php
<?php
return [
    'bar' => csrf_token()
];
```

that is enough to crash Laravel 5.

Comment: you need to provide some code...

Comment: I've provided some example code.

Comment: What are you trying to do? How do you expect to return a csrf_token from the config? That makes no sense? You should get getting the csrf_token through your requests....?

Comment: It does make little sense, but I have a use for it. If you use the package intervention/imagecache, there is a 'route' configuration key. If you set the route to your csrf_token, only who has a session on your site can access that route. Works very well in Laravel 4.2.

Comment: So just use middleware to protect the route? I'm still not following...

Comment: thanks for trying to help. The route is provided by the package: http://image.intervention.io/use/url

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve but this seems to be the wrong way. A config file is absolutly not a place where you would store a csrf token.

What is the purpose of it ? Wouldn't you rather disable the csrf check for a particular request ?

Comment: I am using the intervention/imagecache package, and that package let's you setup a route for your image manipulation, but that route is specified in a config file. Setting the route to your csrf_token() means that only someone with a session on your site would be able access that route. And that worked in Laravel 4, but it does not in 5. I had to go entirely another way, but I already solved it. thank you.